# Broken pipe error when using @shared_task in Django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I am utilizing the celery library to execute tasks in the background even when the user closes or refreshes the page. Since the task takes some time, I opted to use celery.

The algorithm works fine as long as I don't refresh or close the page. However, I encounter the "Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 56578)" error when it occurs. I also attempted to update the account after executing nonFollowers_users(), but I received an error stating that the MySQL server had gone away.

```
for id in accounts:
   account = Account.objects.get(id=id)
   
   #below method is @shared_task from celery
   nonFollowers_users(account, count, sleep)
   try:
      return JsonResponse({'success': True})
   except (ConnectionResetError, BrokenPipeError):
      # the connection was closed, return a response with an appropriate status code
      return HttpResponse(status=499)
```

Comment: Can you share what `nonFollowers_users` is doing? I'm also wondering if it is necessary to do this in a dedicated task anyway?

Comment: I've never used Celery, but I've done similar things using the `@start_new_thread` decorator from https://itecnote.com/tecnote/python-multithreading-for-python-django/  - simple and easy to use, so thought I'd show you the option.
I'd recommend wrapping the whole `for`, so your not starting 2,000 threads tho.
and It returns to the User Instantly, so the user would only see a ~**thread started** msg; they can continue browsing and they will never get a reply if the thread was successful or not. Seems more like what you're going for

Comment: `nonFollowers_users` is calling some external APIs and it is processing some data. It takes time until it is done ~5 min. Preferably, I want to update a value in `org.task`, `processing (bool)` after `nonFollowers_users()` is executed, but same, I get a broken pipe error, and something about mysql server is gone.

Comment: @Nealium is `@start_new_thread` decorator working on background even if the user closed the browser?

Comment: @PaulViorel Yep. I use them for a couple of scripts that depend on an external slower db, I don't want my users waiting around! I can write an example of how I usually do it, if you want.

Comment: @Nealium if that works to update database even if the user closes the browser, I would like to see an example. I would appreciate your efforts trying to help me.

Comment: @Nealium, found the issue. I created a new mysql.connector connection, and I call it at the end of task. Somehow, if the user close/change the browser, when it reaches the Model.save(), it crashes. So with a ne mysql.connector works, but I do not know if it a good practice.

Comment: I don't see any issue with manually making a connector, minus if you ever switch to postgres or another db you'll have to refactor it, but idk!
I'd recommend seeing if there's a way to `close` the connection and make sure it's not sitting there waiting after you've finished

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. This is my basic structure:

#### General

I believe it's generally self explanatory, the only curve ball is the `lock` system.
This exists so you don't spin up multiple threads that could conflict. Because of this
you don't call the threaded function **directly** you instead use a pass through- `thread_switchboard` in the example- so you can immediately return the thread status

I personally use `{thread}.lock` files. I also added a cache version, that's objectively better, but I think It would only work in a production env

#### Structure (`tree`)

```
.
├── my_django
│   └── settings.py
├── common
│   ├── decorators.py
│   ├── threaded_functions.py
│   └── tmp
│       └── .gitignore
└── my_app
    └── views.py
```

#### decorators.py

```py
def start_new_thread(function):
    from threading import Thread

    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        t = Thread(target=function, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    return decorator
```

#### threaded_functions.py

```py
from common.decorators import start_new_thread

# Thread Helpers
#   for keeping track of which ones are currently running
#       so we don't spin up duplicates
def thread_storage():
    use_cache = False
    return use_cache

def create_thread_lock(name):
    from datetime import datetime
    details = {
        'start_time':  datetime.now(),
    }
    if thread_storage():
        from django.core.cache import cache
        seconds = 600  # 10 min
        cache.set(f'Thread:{name}', details, seconds)
    else:
        import json
        with open(f'common/tmp/{name}.lock', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(details, sort_keys=True, indent=2))

def is_running(name):
    # You could even pull data out of storage, like start_time
    if thread_storage():
        from django.core.cache import cache
        return bool(cache.get(f'Thread:{name}'))
    else:
        import os
        return os.path.isfile(f'common/tmp/{name}.lock')
    return False

def remove_thread_lock(name):
    if thread_storage():
        from django.core.cache import cache
        cache.delete(f'Thread:{name}')
    else:
        import os
        target = f'common/tmp/{name}.lock'
        if os.path.isfile(target)
            os.remove(target)

# Thread Helpers - Done

# Actual Threads
#   We **don't** want to call these directly (see next block for call)

@start_new_thread
def threaded_nonfollowers(request, name):
    # Wrapped so we can handle errors
    try:
        # do long actions inside here!
        accounts = request.POST.get('accounts').split(',')  # or something?
        for account_id in accounts:
           account = Account.objects.get(id=account_id)

           # Do actual contents of nonFollowers_users right here


        # remove lock, thread spinning down
        remove_thread_lock(name)

    except Exception as e:
        # Crash
        # - Remove Lock
        remove_thread_lock(name)

        # Send crash report 
        #   Django doesn't report thread crashes by default (odd)
        #
        # We passed `request` this entire time just so the error report will be
        #   usable to recreate the problem (POST data)
        import sys
        import logging
        logger = logging.getLogger('django')
        logger.exception(sys.exc_info(), extra={'status_code': 500, 'request': request})

# Actual Threads - Done


# Thread Handler
#   Could break these up, to be more specific (ex: est times) but heck- switchboard!

def thread_switchboard(request, name):
    threaded_functions_by_name = {
        'nonfollowers': threaded_nonfollowers,
    }

    func = threaded_functions_by_name.get(name, None)  # <- love these
    if func:
        # is valid function, is it running?
        if not is_running(name):
            # not running, start function, return msg
            func(request, name)
            return {'status': True, 'msg': 'Started thread'}
        return {'status': False, 'msg': 'Thread is already running'}
    return {'status': False, 'msg': 'Invalid function'}
```

#### Views.py

```py
from django.http import Http404, JsonResponse

def account_nonfollowers_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # Status:
        #   True  -> Good!
        #   False -> Bad!
        data = {'status': False}  # assume bad

        if request.POST.get('accounts'):
            # Post is as expected.. continue..

            from common.threaded_functions import thread_switchboard
            data = thread_switchboard(request, name='nonfollowers')
            # - will immediately return:
            #   a: True  + Started
            #   b: False + Running
            #   c: False + Invalid

        else:
            data['msg'] = 'accounts were not provided'

        return JsonResponse(data)

    raise Http404
```

#### tmp/.gitignore (.locks)

```
*
*/
!.gitignore
```

Ignore all tmp files but commit the existance of the folder by including the .gitignore

---

#### Side Notes

The main problem with the solution is if the server goes down, before deleting
the .lock file, it won't start the thread until it's removed- hense the cache's `expire` sort of mitigates this.
I've built around this by adding an `expire` timestamp (now+est+grace) to my .lock and instead of just `file exists` I also check against that expire.
But I've found this is an edge case.. Functionally it's a good core and you can make it as complex, or not, as you want.
Let me know if you run into problems! (: